# Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_bluetooth.xml

Tags: android

My app is working fine on api 23.

However in api lower than 19, when I try to open the app, it throws an error, although I don't have an image view in my mainlayout:

> 04-15 15:46:37.196 25249-25249/io.github.swarajsaaj.otpblogdemo
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{io.github.swarajsaaj.otpblogdemo/io.github.swarajsaaj.INFINITY.bluetoothchat.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error
>   inflating class android.widget.ImageView
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                          Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39:
>   Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                                                             at
>   io.github.swarajsaaj.INFINITY.bluetoothchat.BluetoothChatFragment.onCreateView(BluetoothChatFragment.java:354)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:619)
>                                                                                             at
>   io.github.swarajsaaj.INFINITY.common.activities.SampleActivityBase.onStart(SampleActivityBase.java:40)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181)
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5336)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227)
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                             at
>   io.github.swarajsaaj.INFINITY.bluetoothchat.BluetoothChatFragment.onCreateView(BluetoothChatFragment.java:354) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:619) 
>                                                                                             at
>   io.github.swarajsaaj.INFINITY.common.activities.SampleActivityBase.onStart(SampleActivityBase.java:40) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5336) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable-hdpi-v4/ic_bluetooth.xml from drawable resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f020062
>
> ```
>                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2842)
>                                                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:126)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:116)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
>                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593) 
>                                                                                       at
> ```
>
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                             at
>   io.github.swarajsaaj.INFINITY.bluetoothchat.BluetoothChatFragment.onCreateView(BluetoothChatFragment.java:354) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:619) 
>                                                                                             at
>   io.github.swarajsaaj.INFINITY.common.activities.SampleActivityBase.onStart(SampleActivityBase.java:40) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5336) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line
>
> ## 1: invalid drawable tag vector
>
> ```
>                                                                                       at
> ```
>
> android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:917)
>                                                                                             at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:858)
>                                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2839)
>                                                                                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
>                                                                                             at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:126) 
>                                                                                             at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:116) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
>                                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                                                             at
>   io.github.swarajsaaj.INFINITY.bluetoothchat.BluetoothChatFragment.onCreateView(BluetoothChatFragment.java:354) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:619) 
>                                                                                             at
>   io.github.swarajsaaj.INFINITY.common.activities.SampleActivityBase.onStart(SampleActivityBase.java:40) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5336) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2227) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
>                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
>                                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please add `BluetoothChatFragment.onCreateView` and the layout it loads to the question... Also, do you have any Bluetooth icons in your res/drawable folders?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please properly format your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Vector drawable are not supported in lower android versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess APIs below 19 do not support some of the XML that is in your file:
`Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector`